# Call to a member function query() on string OOP PHP

Tags: php, oop

I'm new to OOP PHP so im trying to learn by doing a few basic things, the error im getting is in the title the query just keeps returning that error.

```html
<?php 

//CONNECTION STARTS HERE
class connection{

 private $host = 'localhost';
 private $username = 'root';
 private $password = '';
 private $database = 'test';
 public $conn;

 public function __construct(){

  return $this->conn = mysqli_connect($this->host, $this->username, $this->password, $this->database) or die("MySQL Error");

 }

}

//USERS STARTS HERE
class users{

 public $db;

 public function __construct($db){

  $this->db = $db;

 }

 public function getAllUsernames($db){

  $query = "SELECT * FROM users";

        //ERROR IS ON THIS LINE
  $all_users = $this->db->query("$query");

  while ($row = $all_users->fetch_assoc()) {
   return $row['username'];
  }

 }
}
```

I have no idea where im going wrong can someone help me get a better understanding of what ive done wrong, I know that I have to clean up a lot of the previous code but as I said im learning and that's another story for now I just want to know what this error means and what's making it..?

Comment: Could you please show us the line in which you instanciate users (and when you initialize $db)

Comment: I do it in index.php include 'functions.php';

 $conn = new connection();

 $users = new users('test');
 $users->getAllUsernames('test');

Comment: The answer will solve your problem. You weren't giving a database to your users but a string ;)

Comment: `$users = new users('test');` <- Really? You pass the string "test" as db connection?!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're not far of actually. I altered your code a bit and instantiated your classes:

```
<?php 

//CONNECTION STARTS HERE
class connection {

    private $host = 'localhost';
    private $username = 'root';
    private $password = '';
    private $database = 'test';
    private $conn;

    public function __construct(){

        $this->conn = mysqli_connect($this->host, $this->username, $this->password, $this->database) or die("MySQL Error");

    }

    public function getConn(){
        return $this->conn;
    }

}

//USERS STARTS HERE
class users {

    private $db;

    public function __construct($db){

        $this->db = $db;

    }

    public function getAllUsernames(){

        $query = "SELECT * FROM users";

        //ERROR IS ON THIS LINE
        $all_users = $this->db->query("$query");
        return $all_users;    
    }
}

$connection = new connection();
$users = new users($connection->getConn());

$allUsers = $users->getAllUsernames();
while ($row = $allUsers->fetch_assoc()) {
        echo $row['username'];
}
```

Comment: Thats really relieving to know I was close =) this works great thank you very much! Also I understand where I was going wrong ill use this as a learning curve

Answer (score 0):

It looks like a syntax error, try something like this:

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM users";
$query = $this->db->prepare($sql);
$query->execute();
return $query->fetchAll();
```